# WPF Modern Charts / Modern Ui

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml, charts, modern-ui

I am new to WPF and am writing a basic app using the excellent Modern UI and Modern Charts projects. As things stand, though, the difference in color between the charts and the rest of the application is substantial - this doesn't look visually pleasing at all.

I can change the background of the charts no problem, but I can't find the exact color used for the Dark Theme on Modern UI. Is there a way to reference it directly, or is there a way to find the color?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can peek the [`BaseDark.xaml` source](https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro/blob/master/MahApps.Metro/Styles/Accents/BaseDark.xaml) to find the color you wanted (copied relevant parts here) :

```
<Color x:Key="BlackColor">#FFFFFFFF</Color>
<Color x:Key="WhiteColor">#FF252525</Color>
<Color x:Key="Gray1">#FFF9F9F9</Color>
<Color x:Key="Gray2">#FF7F7F7F</Color>
<Color x:Key="Gray7">#FF7E7E7E</Color>
<Color x:Key="Gray8">#FF454545</Color>
<Color x:Key="Gray10">#FF2F2F2F</Color>
<Color x:Key="GrayNormal">#FF7D7D7D</Color>
<Color x:Key="GrayHover">#FFAAAAAA</Color>
<Color x:Key="FlyoutColor">#FF2B2B2B</Color>
```

You can also reference the color resource directly using it's `Key` value as a `SataticResource`.

Comment: Excellent - I should have thought of looking at the source code!